# Angular 2 ng2-nouislider custom steps?

Tags: angular, nouislider

I am using ng2-nouislider for an angular 2 proyect, so far I am unable to specify custom steps.
For the moment I have in my template file:

```
<nouislider [tooltips]="true" [min]="mensualidadesMin" [max]="mensualidadesMax" [step]="mensualidadesStep" [(ngModel)]="mensualidadesValue" (ngModelChange)="mensualidadesOnChange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></nouislider>
```

And in my typescript file I have:

```
this.mensualidadesMin = 1;
    this.mensualidadesMax = 30;
    this.mensualidadesStep = 1;
```

I would like to have custom steps.
like: 1, 3, 6, 12, 18, and so on.

Whenever I try to change step variable as number[] it does not work either.
And when I try to use range or pipes it does not work either.

I have read and found a lot of uisliders and some are not for angular2, and tried to include them as external import but did not work either.

Do you know what uislider to use in angular 2 that can allow me to set custom steps or how can I achieve it with current one.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed src code of nguisldier and found that there are some options inside config, so far I did this:

in the html template I added the config :

```
<div id="plazos_slider">
    <nouislider style="margin-top:45px;" [config]="mensualidadesConfig" [(ngModel)]="mensualidadesValue" (ngModelChange)="mensualidadesOnChange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></nouislider>
</div>
```

and in my ts file:

```
mensualidadesConfig: any = {
    snap: true,
    start: [1],
    range: {
      'min': 1,
      '14%': 3,
      '28%': 6,
      '42%': 12,
      '56%': 18,
      '70%': 24,
      'max': 30
    },
    pips: {
      mode: 'values',
      values: [1, 3, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30],
      density: 4,
    }
  }
```

Also I managed to hide through css normal pips and only left large pips.
I wrapped all modified css iniside plazos_slider id to avoid affecting original css as I can use nguislider further.